# Condition if a document has guideline

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

I need a script that will check if there is any guidelines in a photo:
if guidecount = 0, will make a selection (Ctrl + A)
otherwise, will do an action or something.
I've tried but it didn't work.

```js
#target photoshop
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var guides = doc.guides;
var numGuides = activeDocument.guides.length;
var savedRuler = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
var x1 = app.activeDocument.width;
var y1 = app.activeDocument.height;
var hGuide1 = guides[0];
var vGuide1 = guides[1];
for (var i = 0; i < guides.count; i++) {
  var guide = guides[i + 1];
  if (guides[0] = i && guides[1] = i) {
    doc.selection.select([x1, y1], SelectionType.REPLACE, 0, false);
  } else {
    alert("nothing")
  };
```

Comment: If you have no guides, you will skip whole loop and all conditions inside,  so no selection will done according to your code. guides[0] meanse "get guide with index 0, not guides.count===0"

Comment: Please tell me how to fix it? 
I am new in javascript.

Comment: @TsunamiLâm Check other threads on SO or in the internet. You can solve this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something useful

```
if (app.activeDocument.guides.length) 
{ 
//your action;
}

else if ( !hasSelection(activeDocument) ) {
activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
}

function hasSelection ()
{
    try{
        return (app.activeDocument.selection.bounds.length>0);
    }
    catch(err){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).